# how to hide original address in address bar in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i working on a application where i want to show image on the screen
when i click in the link this link open in the address bar

```
http://localhost:8080/JobScholar/storage/app/public/newpaper_jobs/230_Govrenment-Of-The-Punjab-Agriculture-Department.jpg
```

but i want to show the bellow link in the address bar mean want o hide original url and show something else

```
http://localhost:8080/JobScholar/store/images/newpaper_jobs/230_Govrenment-Of-The-Punjab-Agriculture-Department.jpg
```

Comment: use .htaccess, find a tutorial online

Comment: You can make a symbolink link between storage/app/public and public/storage: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002665/how-to-access-pdf-file-from-storage-directly-from-browser/46003078#46003078